# System Verilog macro using strings

Tags: macros, system-verilog

I would like to create a system verilog macro and pass a string variable to it.
I've read another thread that uses `define to define a string and pass that`STRING_NAME which works but I need the following.

```
`define STRINGIFY(x) `"x`"
```

I want `REG_PATH` to be converted to the `string` which is used as a parameter.

```
`define mirror(REG_PATH) \
   $display(`STRINGIFY(REG_PATH)``other text);
```

When used I would like to pass the string using a string variable.

```
string register_path = "my string"
`mirror(register_path)
```

I have not tried this code but I know you can pass a `string` variable to a `macro`.
That is why I use the `STRINGIFY(REG_PATH)`.

Answer (score 0):

If requirement is to just display , as string is already passed into the macro and it can be used directly without needing any conversion in the display.

```
define mirror(REG_PATH) \
   $display("%s ``other text",REG_PATH);

string register_path = "my string";

initial
   `mirror(register_path)
```

Also strings can be concatenated directly.

```
`define mirror(REG_PATH) \
   {REG_PATH," other text"}
initial
  $display(`mirror(register_path));
```

Option 3

```
 `define mirror(REG_PATH)  \
 $display("%s otherstring",$psprintf("%s",REG_PATH));
 initial
       `mirror(register_path)
```

Option 4

```
`define mirror(REG_PATH) \
    $psprintf("%s",REG_PATH)

initial
begin
  $display(`mirror(register_path));
end
```

Comment: The $display is just for the example. I want to assign register_path= "string" but this not result in the $display displaying "string". It will display "register_path".

Comment: psprintf can be used . As the content of register_path is needed and its value is set at run time  .       `define mirror(REG_PATH) 
    $display("%s other string",$psprintf("%s",REG_PATH));

Comment: But if I call `mirror(string_parameter) and string_parameter = "My String", I will not get "My String" printed in the $display. I will get "string_parameter" as is printed.

Comment: Got it , but if we don't use `define STRINGIFY(x) `"x`" we should get better result, option 3 and option 4 does generate  "my string"  as the simulation output in candence , would that work ?

Comment: STRINGIFY(x) doesn' work either, so I'm no longer using that as an option. option 3 and 4 do not work if I call `mirror(my_string_variable) and my_string_variable="register_path"; This does not get printed. "my_string_variable" is seen as the string and gets displayed.

Comment: i re-ran option 3 & 4 in 2 simulators ( vcs and ncsim ) and both print the value in the my_string_variable i.e. "register_path" , my guess is that a copy of the older macro or STRINGIFY  maybe there somewhere in files overriding  the new definition causing "my_string_variable" to be printed .

Comment: Try to run this code. It will not display "George" . You will need to replace the string variable with the reg if your not using a simulator that supports string.                                                                                                         `define STRINGIFY(x) `"x`"

`define mirror(reg_path) $display(`STRINGIFY(reg_path));               
    
module test;
  
  string reg_path = "George";
  
 //reg [8*6:1] reg_path="George";

  initial begin
    `mirror(reg_path)
  end
  
endmodule

Comment: Yes you are right , it will not because macro STRINGILY will treat the x as a string and will not do any substitution , it will ignore the input parameter (x) . Try to run this code instead it will print George .      ` define STRINGIFY(x) $psprintf("%s",x)
` define mirror(reg_path) $display(` STRINGIFY(reg_path));
module test;
string reg_path = "George";
//reg [8*6:1] reg_path="George";
initial
begin
 `mirror(reg_path)
end
endmodule    // ``  needs to be edited

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with this. Since the macro is a compile time feature, there will be no run time translation of a string. All I need to do is pass the object instead of a string because the thing I want to pass looks like a string but it's accualy an object.  `define mirror(x) x.mirror_task() prepends the object to the mirror task in the objects class.